# HTTP Cache-Control Header

Tags: http, caching

When I test my site using http://www.webpagetest.org/. It says that I have not set cache expiration header on the home page. When I curl, I see it is set:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 23 Mar 2016 22:31:17 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Cache-Control: max-age=691200, public
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Request-Id: aa9fc904-2af6-4649-bbb2-dfc308172c08
ETag: W/"0011b34ba2dd655ce7380a1014310370"
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Runtime: 0.010013
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger 5.0.25
Set-Cookie: request_method=HEAD; path=/; secure
Set-Cookie: _lafon_session=V21Yc1RlSUlRPT0%3Ddaea; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
Status: 200 OK
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Any ideas on why webpagetest.org thinks the header is not set?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.webpagetest.org/ wrongly expects Expires header to be set, forgetting about full analog with higher priority - max-age.
Everything is ok with your site.